# How do I allow null textbox when using bindingsource Find method?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB please assist. I have an application where I search using combo box and two textboxes. Now it is not always when all textboxes have text. Sometimes the user can search using one textbox. My problem is when I leave out a textbox that searches an integer column is using binding source find method I get : 'Input string was not in a correct format.' because the textbox is empty. My database is access database and I am searching from a gridview binding source. How can I allow txtboxIdSize to be ignored if not used? My code below:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    TblDiesBindingSource.Filter = $"Descript LIKE '%{txtDescription.Text.Trim()}%'"
    TblDiesBindingSource.Position = TblDiesBindingSource.Find("IDSIZE", txtIdSize.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: We shouldn't have to explain how an `If` statement works. That's as fundamental as you can get, so it doesn't really matter how new you are.

Comment: `dim index as Integer If Integer.TryParse(txtIdSize.Text, index) Then TblDiesBindingSource.Position = TblDiesBindingSource.Find("IDSIZE", index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
If txtboxIdSize.TextLength > 0 then
    TblDiesBindingSource.Filter = $"Descript LIKE '%{txtDescription.Text.Trim()}%'"
    TblDiesBindingSource.Position = TblDiesBindingSource.Find("IDSIZE", txtIdSize.Text)
End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Shouldn't it do something (like clear filter) if the text box is empty?

Comment: @Community who asked?

Comment: @Craig shouldve wouldve couldve craig, if it works it works. Dont fix if it aint broke type beat.